# Where do Solidity global variables retrieve from?

Tags: solidity, tx.origin

We can see all global variables listed [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/units-and-global-variables.html#special-variables-and-functions). About tx.origin, Where does its value retrieve from? The in processing transaction? Who does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the link you provided it's a global variable.
meaning accessible in any contract and from any transaction.
The value is retrieved from the transaction sent like said.

Who does what ?

tx.origin is an EOA(Externally Owned Account) since any interaction will always be initiated by an EOA. A contract cannot automatically initiate a tx.